# How to connect queue managers for WebSphere MQ 7.0 distributed publish/subscribe

Tags: proxy, distributed, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

As always, IBM documenation is great for what it tells you but leaves important details out. Apologies if this is already answered here - the search terms are unfortunately mostly generic or at least ambiguous and I have looked through a few hundred questions with no luck.

I have two (IBM i) servers, each with a single WMQ 7.0 queue manager. I have two channels running between them - one each direction.

I have a topic defined on "server A" with Publication and Subscription Scopes of "All" and Proxy Subscription Behaviour of "Force".

I have a subscription defined on "server B" with Scope "All".

Everything is up and running but when I drop a message into the topic on server A (using MQ Explorer), nothing appears on server B.

I have read about the "proxy subscriptions" required to make this work but I cannot for the life of me figure out how these get created.

Any assistance appreciated. I've got this far (never used pub/sub before) in a few hours only to trip at this hurdle.

You have to setup a hierarchy between these two queue managers for publications to flow to queue manager on B.

You have to setup a hierarchy between these two queue managers for publications to flow to queue manager on B.

Assuming queue manager on A as parent and queue manager on B as child, you have to issue "ALTER QMGR PARENT ()" in a RUNMQSC prompt of queue manager on B. This will create the hierarchy between two queue managers. Once a subscription is created on queue manager on B, a proxy subscription will automatically flow to queue manager on A.    Assuming queue manager on A as parent and queue manager on B as child, you have to issue "ALTER QMGR PARENT ()" in a RUNMQSC prompt of queue manager on B. This will create the hierarchy between two queue managers. Once a subscription is created on queue manager on B, a proxy subscription will automatically flow to queue manager on A.

EDIT: More detail on my configuration (with slightly more meaningful - to me - server names)

On server A7:

```
Queue manager A7.QUEUE.MANAGER 
Sender channel A7.TO.A2 with transmission queue A7.TO.A2 
Alias queue A2.QUEUE.MANAGER pointing to A7.TO.A2 
Receiver channel A2.TO.A7
```

In server A2:

```
Queue manager A2.QUEUE.MANAGER 
Sender channel A2.TO.A7 with transmission queue A2.TO.A7 
Alias queue A7.QUEUE.MANAGER pointing to A2.TO.A7 
Receiver channel A7.TO.A2 
I then issued ALTER QMGR PARENT('A7.QUEUE.MANAGER')
```

I have the topic on A7 and after issuing the ALTER (above) I added a subscription on A2 to the topic.

```
display pubsub type(ALL)                               
3 : display pubsub type(ALL)                      
AMQ8723: Display pub/sub status details.               
QMNAME(A2.QUEUE.MANAGER) TYPE(LOCAL) 

display pubsub type(ALL)                               
1 : display pubsub type(ALL)                      
AMQ8723: Display pub/sub status details.               
QMNAME(A7.QUEUE.MANAGER) TYPE(LOCAL)
```

Answer (score 3):

Cluster the two QMgrs and advertise the topic to the cluster.  WMQ will then make publications available across the cluster.

*On QMGR01*

```
# Make the QMgr a cluster repository
ALTER QMGR REPOS('CLUSTERNAME')

# Create CLUSRCVR and advertise to cluster
# Substitute your CONNAME parms, QMgr name, channel names, etc.
DEF CHL(CLUSTERNAME.QMGR01) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) +
    TRPTYPE(TCP) +
    CONNAME('127.0.0.1(1414)') +
    CLUSTER('CLUSTERNAME') +
    REPLACE

# Create topic object and advertise to cluster
DEF TOPIC('ROOT') TOPICSTR('ROOT') CLUSTER('CLUSTERNAME') REPLACE
```

*On QMGR02*

```
# Always create CLUSRCVR first and advertise to cluster
# Substitute your CONNAME parms, QMgr name, channel names, etc.
DEF CHL(CLUSTERNAME.QMGR02) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) +
    TRPTYPE(TCP) +
    CONNAME('127.0.0.1(1415)') +
    CLUSTER('CLUSTERNAME') +
    REPLACE

# Then conecct to the repos and advertise the CLUSSDR to the cluster too
# Substitute your CONNAME parms, QMgr name, channel names, etc.
DEF CHL(CLUSTERNAME.QMGR01) CHLTYPE(CLUSSDR) +
    TRPTYPE(TCP) +
    CONNAME('127.0.0.1(1414)') +
    CLUSTER('CLUSTERNAME') +
    REPLACE
```

Now you can publish to the topic that was advertised to the cluster:

On QMgr01

```
amqspub ROOT/Whatever QMGR01
```

On QMgr02

```
amqssub ROOT/Whatever QMGR02
```

You don't have to name your object `ROOT` or use that as the top of the topic namespace. This was an arbitrary example and you can use anything you want. In Production you would probably have some topic objects at the 2nd or 3rd level in the topic hierarchy to hang access control lists from.  Generally it is these objects that are used to advertise the topics to the cluster.

Some additional notes:

- You cannot advertise `SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC` or `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.TOPIC` to the cluster.
- A clustered topic need be defined on only one node in the cluster.  It can be any node but it's a good practice to advertise it on the primary full repository. That way you know where all your clustered topic objects are defined in one place and the repository is (or should be) highly available.
- If there are local and clustered topic objects that overlap, the local one takes precedence.

Please see *[Creating a new cluster topic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_new_clustertopic.htm)* for more info.  Also, *[Creating and configuring a queue manager cluster](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_cluster_configuring.htm)* has tasks to create the cluster and add QMgrs to it.  However, I tested with the above on my Windows host and in this minimal cluster, the pub/sub worked great.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to not go the cluster route for now but if I do I shall most certainly refer to your excellent info.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup a hierarchy between these two queue managers for publications to flow to queue manager on B.

Assuming queue manager on A as parent and queue manager on B as child, you have to issue "ALTER QMGR PARENT ()" in a RUNMQSC prompt of queue manager on B. This will create the hierarchy between two queue managers. Once a subscription is created on queue manager on B, a proxy subscription will automatically flow to queue manager on A.

Comment: Thanks. This should be enough to get my proposed scenario working (where there is a clearly defined publishing system and the rest will be subscribers). But in a general sense, does this imply subscriptions will also flow the other way? We have multiple dev/test boxes where it may be useful to have each box subscribing to the other's publications.

Comment: Something still isn't right.

I've done a lot more reading with this hierarchy in mind. I realised I needed to add an alias queue with the name of the foreign queue manager so that the local queue manager could find it, but I still cannot see the subscription propagating (I'd expect to see it as a subscription entry on the parent?) and neither is the test publication message getting through.

Comment: Yes, proxy subscription will flow the other way also.

Comment: I have setup a hierarchy on my local box and it works great, I can receive publications at child qmgr. Two qmgrs, MQP and MQC. MQP is parent and have setup sender channels at both qmgrs with auto definition of channels enabled. Altered parent for MQC with MQP as parent. Using amqspub and amqssub sample applications I can publish messages are MQP and receive the same at MQC.